# MySQL select where in concatenated value

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `orders` where I have a column with ids concatenated example this refers to multiple product ids example how it is stored: 454,678 and if I want to select the table products inner joining the table orders `where products.id in (orders.productids)` it will only list one row but if I do the same select and put `where products.id in (454,678)` then it lists me the two rows.

Since the values are already concatenated to be able to use on the IN condition then it should work is there somehow it can read the two id's concatenated?

Comment: What does your query look like now?

Comment: Your design of storing multiple id values in a single column "seems like a win", but it introduces problems with *performance* and *data integrity*. I strongly recommend you read Chapter 2 of Bill Karwin's excellent book "**SQL Antipatterns: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming**". (Yes, it's possible to write a query that will do what you want, but I don't think it's a good idea to give you an example, because that promote your usage of a bad design.)

Answer (score 2):

Just take some time, and create a link table for the ordered product_id

*orders_products*:

- order_id (PK)
- product_id (PK)
- amount
- selling_price

This has many advantages, for example you can use indexes for joins

Comment: thank you i tought on that but i wanted to avoid that to avoid making more queries during the booking process so i tried to put all in one column, isn't there a way to do the query?

Comment: There is always a way, but this shouldn't be the one to follow.

Comment: @user1361389: yes, there's "a way to do the query", but anyone providing you that query isn't really doing you any favors. Storing id values in a comma separated list is just a bad idea; your design is trying to "avoid making more queries", but what that's really going to do is 1) make the queries less efficient, and 2) disable the ability of the database to enforce referential integrity.